# How to force UI update before execution of an action with MVVM?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, mvvm, dispatcher

So i ran into a ui update problem. I want to be able to execute a function **A**, inside function **A** there is a call **B** which takes long time ,so when function A's execution come to the function B i want to Change view to ProgressView, and show progress on the fly.

What i want to achieve :

- Call to a function A
- Execution of A begins
- Function B is
  called
- Function B opens ProgressDialog and show progress while
  Function A is waiting to be allowed to process
- Function B finishes
- Function A can continue
- Function A finishes

I found out that if i want to update UI i have to use Application Dispatcher which will execute an action on UI thread.

FUnction B:

```
Public Sub ShowWaitingScreen(workItems As List(Of WorkItem)) Implements IViewsLogic.ShowWaitingScreen
    Dim waiting As WaitingDialogViewModel = New WaitingDialogViewModel(workItems, Sub() HideDialog())

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, Sub()
                                                                       _shell.DialogViewModel = waiting
                                                                                  waiting.StartWorker
                                                                   End Sub)


End Sub

   Public Class WaitingDialogViewModel
        Inherits ViewModelBase
        Implements IDialog
        Public Sub New(workItems As List(Of WorkItem), completeAction As Action)
            _completeAction = completeAction
            _workItems = workItems
            ProgressValue = 0
            StatusMessage = "Preparing"
        End Sub

        'Private WithEvents _worker As BackgroundWorker
        Private _completeAction As Action
        Private _progressValue As Integer
        Private _statusMessage As String
        Private ReadOnly _workItems As List(Of WorkItem)

        Public Property ProgressValue As Integer
            Get
                Return _progressValue
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)

                _progressValue = value
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, Sub()
                                                                                         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() ProgressValue)
                                                                                     End Sub)
            End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub StartWorker()
        For i As Integer = 1 To _workItems.Count()
            ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(100 / (i + 1))), "Executing " + i.ToString() + " out of " + _workItems.Count().ToString())
            _workItems(i - 1).WorkerAction.Invoke()
        Next
        ReportProgress(100, "Dome")
        _completeAction.Invoke()
    End Sub


    Public Property StatusMessage As String
        Get
            Return _statusMessage
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _statusMessage = value
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, Sub()
                                                                                     RaisePropertyChanged(Function() StatusMessage)
                                                                                 End Sub)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub ReportProgress(progress As Integer, text As String)
        ProgressValue = progress
        StatusMessage = text
    End Sub

End Class
```

The problem i am facing right now is that results are inconsistent, sometimes WaitingDialogViewModel is shown, sometimes its not. How do i force UI update before i start execution of progress?

Answer (score 0):

The view model should invoke `PropertyChanged` event to notify the UI elements that they should update themselves. If you do not provide a specific prop name in `PropertyChangedEventArgs` (i.e. just pass `null`), then *all* bound controls are updated.